# How to separate one column from a DataFrame in Python / Jupyter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

I'm trying to the convert the below DataFrame into Series:

[image: DataFrame]

The columns "Emerging Markets" and "Event Driven" are of interest to me. So, I create a new DataFrame by using the code below:

```
columns = ['Emerging Markets','Event Driven'] #Indicate which columns I want to use
TargetData = Hedgefunds[columns]
```

[image: Targetdata]

But now I want to create two series, one for "Emerging Markets" and one for "Event Driven" but I'm can't figure out how to do it. I used the code below (same logic as above) but it does not work:

```
Emerging_Markets_Column = ['Emerging Markets']
EM = TargetData['Emerging_Markets-Column']
```

What would be the best way to go about separating the columns from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use the first dataframe as reference and try .

```
EM = Hedgefunds['Emerging Markets']
ED = Hedgefunds['Event Driven']
```